# Magento cart SSL issue submitting data to an insecure location

Tags: google-chrome, magento, ssl, cart

I have an issue with SSL on my magento cart page.
For some reason submitting data is not being done via HTTPS.

In Google chrome I get the following error:

The page at '**https: //www .MYSTORE.nl/checkout/cart/**' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at '**http: //www .MYSTORE.nl/checkout/cart/updatePost/**': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.(index):418

The page at '**https: //www.MYSTORE.nl/checkout/cart/**' was loaded over HTTPS, but is submitting data to an insecure location at '**http: //www.MYSTORE.nl/checkout/cart/couponPost/**': this content should also be submitted over HTTPS.

So Google chrome is saying that the cart page isn't fully secure. Other browsers say there's no SSL certificate at all.

SSL in the checkout is working fine.

- Webserver rewrites is set to: YES
- Secure/Unsecure Base URLS are correctly configured (**double checked!**)
- Use secure URLS in frontend is set to: YES

I've searched the web but couldn't find a solution. Does anyone know what could be wrong?
All help is very appreciated!

Magento version 1.6.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We updated to magento 1.9.1.0.
Now the SSL issue is resolved.